# Creating a Batch file that produces max 10 log files and deletes the oldest

Tags: batch-file

Hey I have a batch script and I want to log it.
I want to produce 10 log files.

x1.log
x2.log
...
x10.log

there should only be max 10 log files in the folder the x1.log is always the newest log created.
that means the log files change name when the script runs.

x1.log becomes x2.log when the script runs and a new x1.log is created and x10.log is deleted because x9.log becomes x10.log

I hope I made it understandable.

Have a great day all

```
IF EXIST N:\projects\Trainee\work\st\M1_Infrastructure_Basics\log\x1.log (
    ren "N:\projects\Trainee\work\st\M1_Infrastructure_Basics\log\x1.log" "x2.log"
    break
    ren "N:\projects\Trainee\work\st\M1_Infrastructure_Basics\log\x2.log" "x3.log"
    ) else (
    echo "file nicht gefunden"
    )
```

some code but it isnt the right way to solve it i figured out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way. Do it all in descending sequence.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%i in (9,-1,1) do (
    set /a num=%%i+1
    if exist x%%i.log move /Y "x%%i.log" "x!num!.log" >nul 2>&1
)
call "%cd%\run.bat" .pdf,"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++" >> 'C:\projects\Traine\work\ad\log\x1.log"
```

Comment: Hey Gerhard I got a Question. How would this code look in BASH ?

Comment: Completely different than this because the one is a windows shell and the other a Linux shell.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a typical mistake: imagine you have five files, x1.log, x2.log, ..., x5.log, and you rename the way you do:

```
REN x1.log x2.log  => x1 will not exist anymore and its contents are in x2
REN x2.log x3.log  => x2 will not exist anymore and its content:
                      in fact the content of x1) will be in x3
...
```

=> You'll end up with just one file, x5.log, containing the content of x1.log.

Therefore I would advise you to work in the opposite way:

```
REN x9.log x10.log
REN x8.log  x9.log
...
```

Good luck :-)

Comment: Thanks alot for the quick reply I will give it a try now !